# How can I close a popup when clicking another one?

Tags: javascript, popup, show

I have a problem.
I have a series of popups and I am not able to make the opened one closing when opening another.
I'd like to have a result in which I open one of them and it closes when I open another.
Here's a piece of my code:

```html
<script>
    function popup0(){
        let popup = document.getElementById('popup0');
        popup.classList.toggle('show');
    }
</script>
<p class = 'popup' onclick = 'popup0()'>El Gringo
    <span class = 'popuptext' id = 'popup0'>
        Each time he loses a life point due to a card played by another player, Gringo draws a random card from the hand of that player (one card for each life).<br>(3 life points)
    </span>
</p><br>
<script>
    function popup1(){
        let popup = document.getElementById('popup1');
        popup.classList.toggle('show');
    }
</script>
<p class = 'popup' onclick = 'popup1()'>Willy the Kid
    <span class = 'popuptext' id = 'popup1'>
        During his turn, he can play any number of 'Bang!' cards.<br>(4 life points)
    </span>
</p><br>
<script>
    function popup2(){
        let popup = document.getElementById('popup2');
        popup.classList.toggle('show');
    }
</script>
<p class = 'popup' onclick = 'popup2()'>Lucky Duke
    <span class = 'popuptext' id = 'popup2'>
        Each time he is required to 'Draw!', he flips the top two cards from the deck and chooses the result he prefers. Both cards are discarded afterwards.<br>(4 life points)
    </span>
</p><br>
<script>
    function popup3(){
        let popup = document.getElementById('popup3');
        popup.classList.toggle('show');
    }
</script>
<p class = 'popup' onclick = 'popup3()'>Kit Carlson
    <span class = 'popuptext' id = 'popup3'>
        During Phase 1 of his turn, he looks at the top three cards of the deck, then chooses two to put into his hand and puts the remaining card back onto the deck, face down.<br>(4 life points)
    </span>
</p><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new function to hide opened popups and call it inside each function.

Like below:

```
    function hideOther(popupElem) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.popuptext:not(#'+popupElem+')').forEach(elem => {
    elem.classList.remove('show');
  });
}

function popup0() {  
  let popup = document.getElementById('popup0');
  hideOther('popup0');
  popup.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

You need to call `hideOther` inside each popup function like here we called it inside `popup0`

**Updated** Passed current id to the function and checked to get only other popups to close

Comment: Thank you so much, I already tried something like that, but (idk why) it didn't work, I surely missed something

Comment: Wait, it causes another problem, popups now don't close on toggle

Comment: Only when clicking another one

Comment: @M1001 Updated please check now.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code to have a list of popup ids, with this ids you can deactivate all other popup when a button is clicked to show a specific popup.

```
 const poppupList = [
    'popup1',
    'popup2',
    'popup3',
  ];
  
function showPopup(popupId){
    let popup = document.getElementById(popupId);
    
    poppupList.forEach((poppupElementId) => {
        if(poppupElementId !== popupId) {
            document.getElementById(poppupElementId).classList.remove('show');
      }
    });
    
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
    console.log('show ' + popupId);
}
```

Link to a online fiddle with a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vmbjwna2/

Comment: In this way popups don't close on toggle, but just clicking another one, I needed both

Comment: Fixed, now the popup toggles

Answer (score 0):

Just look up the element with the active class and remove it. I changed the code to not use inline events and use data attribute to determine what to show to remove a lot of repeated code.

```js
function popup(elem) {
  const toggles = document.querySelector(elem.dataset.toggles);
  const active = document.querySelector('.popuptext.show');

  if (active && active !== toggles) {
    active.classList.remove('show');
  }

  toggles.classList.toggle('show');
}

document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggles]").forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", () => popup(elem));
});
```

```css
.popuptext {
  display: none;
}

.popuptext.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class='popup' data-toggles="#popup1">Willy the Kid
  <span class='popuptext' id='popup1'>
        During his turn, he can play any number of 'Bang!' cards.<br>(4 life points)
    </span>
</p><br>

<p class='popup' data-toggles="#popup2">Lucky Duke
  <span class='popuptext' id='popup2'>
        Each time he is required to 'Draw!', he flips the top two cards from the deck and chooses the result he prefers. Both cards are discarded afterwards.<br>(4 life points)
    </span>
</p><br>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time buddy, @CodeThing already resolved it, have a nice day

Comment: The other solution is pretty bad since you are repeating a lot of code. Make a change and you need to do it in a bunch of places.

Comment: About the 'repeted code', I just copy-pasted the page source shown on my website, it is made via a php algorith, I wrote it only one time (with a foreach)

Comment: Well that is how many extra bytes being loaded every time you load the page. I do not care about the check, just trying to tell you it is not the best solution. And there is no reason you need to loop over all the elements to hide them when only one is possible to be shown.

Comment: I am going to try it, thx

Comment: I tried what you wrote and it is not working, I think something about I was using 'visibility: hidden/visible' instead of 'display: none/block'

Comment: So use your classes, the CSS in this was just so it worked in the demo.

Comment: I did it, but still not working, I upload the code as edit

Comment: I am cancelling the edit, it is just a waste of time for people with the same problem at this time